# Object default to a function if no objects within are defined

Tags: javascript, function, object, default, hierarchy

Let's say I have the following objects:

```
Fxy.commands={
    group:{
        add:function(msg){
```

So, of course, `Fxy.commands.group.add('something')` will do whatever that function does. But, what if I call `Fxy.commands.group('something')`? Well, I honestly don't know how to make it handle that. That's what I'm asking: how would I make an object default to a function if no object within it is called? Obviously the code above won't work because it has no default function as I don't even know where it would be placed. If it is possible, how would it be done? If not, simply say so, but please also suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects too, so you can assign properties to them:

```
Fxy.commands = {
    group: function(msg) {}
};

Fxy.commands.group.add = function(msg){};
```

**Update:** (as requested)

If you don't want to write `Fxy.commands.group` over and over again (which is actually not that bad, because it makes clear where the functions are assigned to), you could create a function which copies properties (like [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)). Here a very basic version:

```
function extend(A, B) {
    for(var prop in B) {
        if(B.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            A[prop] = B[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var funcs = {
     add: function(){},
     remove: function(){},
     ...
};

extend(Fxy.commands.group, funcs);
```

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, would it also be possible to do `Fxy.commands.group:{add:function(){}}` instead of `Fxy.commands.group.add=function(){}` for every new object within `group`?

Comment: Could you get away with `group: function() { this.add = function () { ... } }`?  Or is this going to refer back to Fxy?

Comment: @Jimmy: No, because you then overwrite `group`. You could create a function though which takes two objects and assignes all the properties of object A to object B (if you don't want to write `Fxy.commands.group.xyz` all the time).

Comment: @g.d.d.c: `this` will refer to `Fxy.commands` in this case, so no, this won't work. It would also reassign the function the whenever `group` is called which is not desired I think.

Comment: @Felix Kling can you give an example? I'm not good with anything else.